# Angular 6 - Class variables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scope, this

If I have a component like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: './...html',
  styleUrls: ['./...scss']
})
export class TestClass implements OnInit {

  testVariable : string = 'Test';

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {}

  printTest(): void{
    console.log(this.testVariable);
  }

}
```

If I call printTest method from an another component, the result will be undefined. Why? How can I figure out this?

Comment: In `printTest`, replace `tetsVariable` with `testVariable`.

Comment: Show us how you call the method from the other component, and how you get the reference to `TestClass` form that other component.

Answer (score 1):

Typo here

```
console.log(this.tetsVariable);
```

should be

```
console.log(this.testVariable);
```